# How to build and deploy meteor app from dev machine to offline production machine?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying out meteor. I've developed a basic webapp that uses mongodb too. Now, this app needs to be deployed on a target machine (win32) with the following requirements.

1. Target machine is just a PC and the person using it is not a dev. So it'd be nice if i can just point them to a single installer (for runtime... i guess some nodejs+mongodb bundle?)
2. Build and deploy the app into some folder their PC. "meteor build" produces a nice zip, but it doesn't seem like a production build i.e. contains a lot of folders with readable javascript. Isn't it possible to just build a single minified js for server-app and a minified js+html+css combo for client-app?
3. Target machine will be mostly off-internet and come online occasionally(once a day or so). I guess this should be okay since users of the app will be just other machines within the LAN.